# Auto-generated controllers by Entity Framework (Web API 2)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Does anyone have an idea why auto-generated controllers in ASP.NET Web API by Entity Framework don't check if given entities are null. Here's an example what you get when you auto-generate a controller for an entity.

If you try posting no content at the controller, a null pointer exception gets thrown. A check against a null value should be there by default, if you ask me. Any ideas why this isn't in ASP.NET Web API 2 by default?

```
// POST: api/MyEntity
[ResponseType(typeof(MyEntity))]
public IHttpActionResult PostMyEntity(MyEntity entity)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    _db.MyEntities.Add(entity);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = entity.Id }, entity);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be the expected functionality? If you try to post nothing to a controller which expects a parameter, there should be an error. Also, shouldn't the `ModelState.IsValid` handle an erronous model state?

Comment: If a user posted nothing, it is indeed a mistake, but it shouldn't result in an unhandled exception. IMHO, the server should respond with a bad request message by default.

Comment: Perhaps it shouldn't be an unhandled exception, but it needs to be an exception. Perhaps it is something you can handle with routing. However, irrelevant of these ideas, that isn't going to be standard practice; everyone will want to handle an exception differently, so offering a basis for implementation is what they're trying to achieve.